# Add Non-control, non-output Ruby code in Slim

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, slim-lang

I'd like to do a Ruby variable assignment in Ruby slim. Apparently the way I did trying to use the control symbol `-` doesn't work. Any ideas how to

(Look at the comments in the code block below).

```
- @locations.each do |station|
  - @sources.each do |source|

    # the following code is meant to be a plain Ruby code for variable assignment
    # how can I do that in Slim?

    - reading = Reading.where(location: station, source: source).order('time').last
    tr
      td = station.name
      td = reading.time.in_time_zone(station.timezone)
      td = reading.source.name
      td = reading.temperature.value.to_s if reading.temperature
```

Comment: That should work. What error did you get?

Comment: Like @faraz already mentioned, what error did you get? Something like `undefined method 'time' for  nil:Nilclass` or something like that? Aside: you probably don't want to do this call in your view, but move it to your controller or model instead.

Comment: @faraz, @newmediafreak. Thanks very much for the comments. And sorry for the late reply, was trying to find out more of the bug. Yes, `undefined method 'time' for nil:Nilclass` is exactly the error I get. The strange thing is when I simply print `reading`, I do get the reading object reference like `#<Reading:0x007fcb46ddf5e0>`. And I can indeed find the time attribute in Rails console

Comment: Apparently, the error I get was indeed not related to slim. After changing to erb, the same error still occurs. It might be something related to the change of my database (which has been changed from Postgres to Sqlite3, I only changed the config/database.yml file and the gemfile). In the end, I resolved by creating a new app using Sqlite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The use of symbol `-` is correct. It can be used for any non-output Ruby code. i.e. The line below is correct and placed at the right indentation in the source code above.

```
- reading = Reading.where(location: station, source: source).order('time').last
```

The error I get was not related to slim. After changing to erb, the same error still occurs. It might be something related to the change of my database (which has been changed from Postgres to Sqlite3, I only changed the config/database.yml file and the gemfile). In the end, I resolved by creating a new app using Sqlite.